# How to calculate HITS (Authority and Hub) score after N iteration using Python Networkx

Tags: python, networkx

I am trying to find HITS (Authority and Hub) score after N iteration using the python Networkx.

Example-

```
import networkx as nx
G1 = nx.DiGraph()
G1.add_edges_from([('A', 'B'),
                   ('A','C'),
                   ('D','C'),
                   ('D', 'C'),
                   ('C', 'A'),
                   ('B','C')
                  ])

#nx.draw_networkx(G1,arrows=True,pos=nx.spring_layout(G1))
```

I get below error for int iterations. How to fix it?

```
nx.hits(G1, max_iter=5)
```

> NetworkXError: HITS: power iteration failed to converge in 5
>   iterations.

Answer (score 1):

The `max_iter` parameters only control the maximum number of iterations for the power iteration. You want to abort the iteration and get the current result. For this you can easily modify the existing implementation of [`nx.hits`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/_modules/networkx/algorithms/link_analysis/hits_alg.html#hits):

```py
import networkx as nx


def hits(graph, iterations, tolarance=1.0e-8):
    hubs = dict.fromkeys(graph, 1.0 / graph.number_of_nodes())
    authorities = {}
    # power iteration, which stops after given iterations or reaching tolerance
    for _ in range(iterations):
        last_hubs = hubs
        hubs = dict.fromkeys(last_hubs.keys(), 0)
        authorities = dict.fromkeys(last_hubs.keys(), 0)
        for node in hubs:
            for neighbor in graph[node]:
                authorities[neighbor] += last_hubs[node] * graph[node][neighbor].get('weight', 1)
        for node in hubs:
            for neighbor in graph[node]:
                hubs[node] += authorities[neighbor] * graph[node][neighbor].get('weight', 1)
        scaling = 1.0 / max(hubs.values())
        for node in hubs:
            hubs[node] *= scaling
        scaling = 1.0 / max(authorities.values())
        for node in authorities:
            authorities[node] *= scaling
        err = sum([abs(hubs[node] - last_hubs[node]) for node in hubs])
        if err < tolarance:
            break
    return hubs, authorities


G1 = nx.DiGraph()
G1.add_edges_from([('A', 'B'),
                   ('A', 'C'),
                   ('D', 'C'),
                   ('D', 'C'),
                   ('C', 'A'),
                   ('B', 'C')
                   ])

print(hits(G1, 5))
# ({'A': 1.0, 'B': 0.7071428571428572, 'C': 0.0017857142857142852, 'D': 0.7071428571428572}, {'A': 0.0025252525252525246, 'B': 0.4141414141414141, 'C': 1.0, 'D': 0.0})
```